# Query only custom fields with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I am executing the following WP_Query on my mysql database:

```
$products = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'posts',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'meta_key',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value' => '_cegg_data_Amazon',
        ),
    ),
));
```

When I `var_dump($product)` I am receiving a long wp_Query object. However, I would only like to receive an object/list of the custom post fields. The below SQL query gives me exactly that back within phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` where meta_key="_cegg_data_Amazon" ORDER BY `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` ASC
```

Any suggestions how to get only the values of the custom fields `_cegg_data_Amazon`. I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to loop through your WP_Query object and create your array (or new obj) with the desired field:

```
$products = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'posts',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'meta_key',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value' => '_cegg_data_Amazon',
        ),
    ),
));

$cegg_data = array(); // initiate the new array


if( $products->have_posts() ) : 

    while( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();

        $cegg_data[] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_cegg_data_Amazon', true); // populate array with the new value

    endwhile;

endif;

wp_reset_query();
```

Now, if you var_dump "$cegg_data" it should contain an indexed array with the custom field values.

NB: the code is untested, just a quick draft ;)

Another and solution you can explore would be "posts_fields" filter documented here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_fields/

Hope this helps and good luck ;)

Francesco